# How to generate bech32 address from the public key? Bitcoin

Tags: node.js, bitcoin, cryptocurrency, bitcoinlib

I am using `bitcoinjs-lib` for bitcoin key pair generation.

I got enough examples to generate legacy address and segwit address from the public key, but for `bech32` address I could not found anything.

`P2PKH` which begin with the number `1`,
eg: `1BvBMSEYstWetqTFn5Au4m4GFg7xJaNVN2`.

`P2SH` type starting with the number `3`,
eg: `3J98t1WpEZ73CNmQviecrnyiWrnqRhWNLy`.

`Bech32` type starting with `bc1`,
eg: `bc1qar0srrr7xfkvy5l643lydnw9re59gtzzwf5mdq`.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many steps involved in it.

`hash160(publickey)` which is `ripemd160(sha256(publickey))`.

After that add `0` Uint8 to the output of bech32 words.

Then using `bech32` encode it with the prefix `bc` for bitcoin.
It will work for litecoin also, change the `bc` to `ltc`.

For Cosmos Atom also, it will work except skip the adding 0 to the ouput of bech32.

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const bech32 = require("bech32");

const sha256Digest = crypto
  .createHash("sha256")
  .update(data, "hex")
  .digest("hex");

const ripemd160Digest = crypto
  .createHash("ripemd160")
  .update(sha256Digest, "hex")
  .digest("hex");

const bech32Words = bech32.toWords(Buffer.from(ripemd160Digest, "hex"));
const words = new Uint8Array([0, ...bech32Words]);
address = bech32.encode("bc", words);
console.log(address);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's filed as BIP 0173. You can find documentation about it in the Bitcoin Wiki.
[Wiki BIP0173](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0173)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just use
`bitcoin.payments.p2wpkh({pubkey:yourpubkey,network });`